# How to transmit php data in ajax form

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a problem with transmitting php data in ajax function.
What I want is to send a html form, in which i have php value from a mysqli_fetch_array. The value is the number of the post, which is my primary key.
Being new to javascript, I don't really know how to do this.
Here is my onclick function code :

```
<script>
 function foo () {
  $.ajax({
    url:"vote.php?no_post=<?php $post ['no_post'] ?>", //what I'd like to do
    type: "POST", //request type
    success:function(result)
    {
     alert(result);
   }
 });
 }
</script>
```

In the php page, I have this fetch array, here we focus on button named "up" :

```
    if(!isset($_POST['more']))
    {
    while($post = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
    echo
        '<p>'.
            '<center>'.
            '<img src="image/'.$post['image_post'].'">'.
            '</center>'.
            '<br/>'.
            '<label>'.$post['desc_post'].'</label>'.
                            '<p>'.
                '<a id="darkBlue" href="account.php?no_post='.$post['no_post'].'">'.'@'.$post['login'].'</a>'.
                            '<p>'.
                '<label>'.$post['time'].'</label>'.
                            '<p>'.
                '<label>'.$post['vote_post'].' points'.'</label>'.
                    '<footer>';

    if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
        echo        '<button class="btn btn-success" name="up" id="up" onclick="foo()">+</button>'.
                '&nbsp'.
                        '<button class="btn btn-danger" name="down" id="down">-</button>'.
                    '&nbsp'.
                            '<a href="commentaire.php?no_post='.$post['no_post'].'" class="btn btn-warning">Comment</a>'.
                    '<hr>';
    }
```

EDIT***

And finally my php page where the sql request is executed :

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['up'])) // 2 buttons on the first html FORM
 {
$req="UPDATE post SET vote_post=vote_post+1
    WHERE no_post=".$_GET['no_post'].""; //picking up the value from my url
$res=mysqli_query($con,$req);
 }

else if (isset($_POST['down']))
{
$req2="UPDATE post SET vote_post=vote_post-1
     WHERE no_post=".$_GET['no_post'].""; //picking up the value from my URL
 $res2=mysqli_query($con,$req2);
 }

 else
     echo 'Error';
?>
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: place `echo` in `url:"vote.php?no_post=<?php echo  $post['no_post'] ?>"`, //what I'd like to do

Comment: Why you use POST if you aren't sending any data in the body?

Comment: if you are sending data  like this : url:"vote.php?no_post=<?php $post ['no_post'] ?>",this is way you send the data using GET post, its visible in URL.. why you using method as POST?  First decide which method you actually want to use.

Comment: What I send with the POST is <?php echo $post ['no_post'] ;?>, it is the item number in my database, it allows me to identify the post that I want to be upvoted. Using only PHP I achieved to set my upvote system with a <form>. Btw I forgot to give you my code in vote.php where I treat the request. Here it is in the latest edit. I keep on working on your solutions, thank you all !

Comment: what's the status of this question? @Julien did an answer below solve it? if so, one of them should be marked as the correct one by accepting it.

Comment: well thank you all for your answers, I'm going to invest on it, when solved I will marked the correct one and tell you more !

Comment: @Julien actually, you should have posted a comment under the answers below, telling them if it didn't work and why. They don't know if it worked for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `echo` in below line.

```
url:"vote.php?no_post=<?php echo $post['no_post'] ?>", //what I'd like to do
```

**EDIT**

As you have used `POST` method, it should be passed in `data` like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"vote.php",
    type: "POST", //request type,
    data: {
       postCount : <?php echo $post['no_post']; ?>
    }
    success:function(result)
    {
     alert(result);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Your answer did not work but helped me to understand a bit more how ajax worked. Sorry for the long time that i took to reply

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
<script>
 function foo () {
  $.ajax({
    url:"vote.php",
    type: "POST", //request type
    data: {no_post: <?php echo '$post['no_post']'?>}
    success:function(result)
    {
     alert(result);
   }
 });
 }
</script>
```

It's better to use `data : [...]` instead of using parameters in url

Comment: Your answer did not work but helped me to understand a bit more how ajax worked. Sorry for the long time that i took to reply