# php variable in ajax doesn't change value

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a button into a while loop on a PHP file. 
The button is associated to a PHP value that is changing with `mysqli_fetch_array`. 
I load only 3 values in my `mysqli_fetch_array`.
 My ajax function has data in it, my problem is that it is only accepting first row's value, and not other rows value. In fact, the function is ok just at the first row of the `mysqli_fetch_array`, and it seems that my code is not working on the other rows, like if PHP loop stopped at first row.

Here is my javscript code (it is declared on the same page of my loop, after the while):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#up").click(function() {
      var varno_commentaire = $("#no_commentaire").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "upvoteCommentaire.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          no_commentaire: varno_commentaire
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
        }
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

And here is my PHP loop :

```
<?php 
while($comm = mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
{
    echo
        '<label class="text-muted">'.$comm['desc_commentaire'].'</label>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<a href="">'.'@'.$comm['login'].'</a>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<label>'.$comm['vote_commentaire'].' points'.'</label>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<input type="text" value="'.$comm['no_commentaire'].'" id="no_commentaire"/>'.
        '<button class="btn btn-default" name="up" id="up">+</button>'.
            '&nbsp'.
        '<button class="btn btn-default" name="down" id="bold" onclick="downvote()">-</button>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<hr/>';
}
?>
```

I hope it will be easy to understand. Any help will be appreciated, I've been stuck on it for a moment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `id` should be different for different buttons... multiple elements should not have same id

Comment: Yeah, the only way you get the value is with `$("#no_commentaire").val()` – how is that supposed to work when you have multiple `#no_commentaire` elements in your page?

Comment: I think you're right, sorry to ask it but would you have any suggestions of what would be the good fetching function ?

Comment: I deleted my comment about using the wrong fetching function, I may have been wrong about it. See the answers below.

Comment: well thank you all for your answers, I'm going to invest on it, when solved I will marked the correct one and tell you more !

Comment: @Julien Remember to comment under answers. [See my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882269/how-to-transmit-php-data-in-ajax-form#comment77565447_44882269) under your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't declare more than once an `id`. ID should be unique. You can pass the ID into a HTML attribute.

Your loop:

```
<?php 
while($comm = mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
{
    echo
        '<label class="text-muted">'.$comm['desc_commentaire'].'</label>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<a href="">'.'@'.$comm['login'].'</a>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<label>'.$comm['vote_commentaire'].' points'.'</label>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<input type="text" value="'.$comm['no_commentaire'].'"/>'.
        '<button class="btn btn-default btn-up" data-id="'.$comm['no_commentaire'].'">+</button>'.
            '&nbsp'.
        '<button class="btn btn-default btn-down" data-id="'.$comm['no_commentaire'].'">-</button>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<hr/>';
}
?>
```

Your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.btn-up").click(function() {
      var varno_commentaire = $(this).data('id');

      $.ajax({
        url: "upvoteCommentaire.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          no_commentaire: varno_commentaire
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
        }
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Your method worked, i just had to change the data-id value to : data-id="'.$comm['no_commentaire'].'"

Comment: Thanks for your help sir !

Answer (score 0):

`ID` are meant to be used only once on the entire page. In your case every element in `while` loop of PHP has same ID. So when you take the value of element by `$("#no_commentaire").val()`, it takes the first element's value ignoring the rest of the elements on the page.

Solution to your problem is to have a `class` instead of `ID` of the elements and access the same by `parent` `child` releationship in the jQuery. So you only get the value of selected/clicked section.

Your PHP code would look something like this,

```
<?php 
while($comm = mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
{
    echo
        '<div class="parent-class">'.
        '<label class="text-muted">'.$comm['desc_commentaire'].'</label>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<a href="">'.'@'.$comm['login'].'</a>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<label>'.$comm['vote_commentaire'].' points'.'</label>'.
            '<p>'.
        '<input type="text" value="'.$comm['no_commentaire'].'" class="no_commentaire"/>'.
        '<button class="btn btn-default up" name="up">+</button>'.
            '&nbsp'.
        '<button class="btn btn-default" name="down" id="bold" onclick="downvote()">-</button>'.
            '<p>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<hr/>';
}
?>
```

and jQuery code would look something like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".up").click(function() {
      var varno_commentaire = $(this).parent().child(".no_commentaire").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "upvoteCommentaire.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          no_commentaire: varno_commentaire
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
        }
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Your up button has two `class` ;)